# Livecode colorNames() function?

Tags: livecode

I am trying to write a program that gets rid of all of the colors with numbers in their names and then puts them into a field. I am running into problems with line 4. Any suggestions?

```
    on mouseup
       global choice
       put colorNames() into choice
       repeat for each line in choice
         if tcolor1 contains "1" || "2" then
             delete tcolor1 from choice
         end if
       end repeat
       put choice into fld "color list"
    end mouseup
```

Comment: Your line should read `repeat for each line myLine in choice` and in the if-statement you should check myLine for numbers. Don't delete the lines from your list but copy the lines to a new list if they have no numbers. Anyway, as you can see in my answer, there is a different way to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you forgot to specify the variable -- tColor -- to represent each line in your choice variable.  Also, when using repeat for each, you're better off building a new list of the results you want, rather than trying to modify the original variable (choice).

Try something like:

```
on mouseUp
   global choice
   put colorNames() into temp
   repeat for each line tColor in temp
      if tColor contains "1" or tColor contains "2" then next repeat -- SKIP UNWANTED RESULTS
      put tColor & return after myColorList -- BUILD A NEW LIST
   end repeat
   delete last char of myColorList -- REMOVE THE LAST RETURN CHARACTER
   put myColorList into choice
   put myColorList into fld "color list"
end mouseUp
```

Also notice you need to actually write out "or" (assuming that's what you're trying do ) -- LiveCode doesn't use a symbol for that operator.

Answer (score 0):

This line puts all color names that don't contain numbers into variable `myList`:

```
filter the colorNames without "*[0-9]*" into myList
```

Comment: This is a good method but the syntax is incorrect. You'll want to put the colornames into MyList before filtering.

Comment: Sorry, you're correct. I forgot about the "into" modifier when I skimmed the response.